# Изображение с формы повреждается ASP.NET 6 C# IFormFile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, input, потоки-данных, filestream

Через `input typ=file` выбираю изображение (несколько изображений). В крентроллер передаю его (их) с помощью `IFormFileCollection`. Пытаюсь сохранить его. Файл сохраняется нечитаемым (возможно, формат не поддерживается). Сохраняю так:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> View(IFormFileCollection images, FeedBack feedBack)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (images.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var image in images)
            {
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(image.FileName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await image.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
             }
          }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Этот кусочек кода выглядит нормально.

Comment: Показывайте остальной код - как вы получаете `image` и что вообще в этой переменной.

Comment: Добавил, правла отформатировал не очень. В самом мнтоде ещё есть сохранение FeedBack в БД, но эту часть я опустил

Comment: В валидации модели потоки в файлах не открываются для каких-нибудь целей?

Comment: Кстати, а в какой каталог файлы сохраняются? В примерах обычно конкретный каталог составляют, а не просто по имени пишут. Вы уверены, что смотрите именно те файлы, которые сохраняются?

Comment: При валидации, вроде, не открываются. По крайней мере я ничего такого не писал, а ранее этого поля не существовало вообще. Сохраняется в каталог проекта пока что. Уверен, что открываю именно те файлы

Comment: Опытным путём определил, что мой код работает везде, кроме того проекта, в котором это нужно

Comment: @CrazyElf действительно выяснилось, что для некоторых целей используется поток, в который помещалось всё содержимое при отправке в контроллер (объяснил сумбурно, потому что сам не совсем понимаю, как это работало). Проблему удалось решить. Спасибо Вам за то, что натолкнули на путь решения!

Comment: @Vladimir Про потоки не я писал, но хорошо, что разобрались )